# AngularJS ui-grid Nested Column Menu

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

ui-grid allows for column menus but they are added one on top of the other. I need to have nested menu items (like this http://www.bootply.com/86684) but I also need to specify custom controls, like check boxes and radio buttons on the nested menu item.

So far, I've spent several hours going through the docs, searching online, and reading the ui-grid code but have not been able to come up with a solution. Looking for some pointers or guidance on how I may be able to achieve this.

Sample configuration of menu items for a column in ui-grid:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    field: 'Column01',
    menuItems: [
        {
            title: 'Outer Scope Alert',
            icon: 'ui-grid-icon-info-circled',
            shown: function() { return true; },
            active: function() { return true; },
            context: $scope,
            action: function($event) {
                this.context.blargh();
            }
        },
        {
            title: 'Grid ID',
            action: function() {
                alert('Grid ID: ' + this.grid.id);
            }
        }
    ]
];
```

Is there a way to completely overwrite the column menu template so that I can specify a nested array of menu items like so? Note also that I would like to specify a template for the individual menu items.

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    field: 'Column01',
    menuItems: [
        {
            title: 'Menu A',
            icon: 'ui-grid-icon-info-circled',
            context: $scope,
            menuItems: [
                {
                    title: 'Menu A1',
                    icon: 'ui-grid-icon-info-circled',
                    template: '<li>' +
                    '    <div class="checkbox">' +
                    '        <label>' +
                    '          <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox 01' +
                    '       </label>' +
                    '    </div>' +
                    '    <div class="checkbox">' +
                    '        <label>' +
                    '          <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox 02' +
                    '       </label>' +
                    '    </div>' +
                    '</li>',
                    action: function($event) {
                        this.context.blarghA1();
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Menu A2',
                    icon: 'ui-grid-icon-info-circled',
                    action: function($event) {
                        this.context.blarghA2();
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Menu A3',
                    icon: 'ui-grid-icon-info-circled',
                    action: function($event) {
                        this.context.blarghA3();
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Menu B',
            action: function() {
                alert('Grid ID: ' + this.grid.id);
            }
        }
    ]
];
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you rephrase? Also, can you share your current attempt?

Comment: @Joum ui-grid allows for column menus but they are added one by one and simply stack on top of each other. I need to have nested menu items like in the link I provided [link](http://www.bootply.com/86684) but I also need to specify custom controls, like check boxes and radio buttons on the nested menu item. So far, I've spent several hours going through the docs, searching online, and reading the ui-grid code but have not been able to come up with a solution.

Comment: @Joum I edited the question a bit. Thanks!

Comment: What I was able to find out is that it's currently (as of Nov. 18, 2015) not feasible with native version. It can probably be modified to act this way, but I don't suspect it to be trivial and/or doable in a single SO question/answer. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3433

Comment: Thanks @Joum. I sort of came to the same conclusion and put in a feature request. I looked at the grid code to see if and how it can be done and there are a lot of challenges!